# tell haproxy or squid to execute a script or http request before perfoming the proxying action

Tags: proxy, execution, squid, haproxy

Is there a way to let haproxy or squid to run a (bash)script (or another http request) before performing the proxying of the incoming requests?

I want to host a userX specific http server(and service) at userX.mydomain.com, but these kind of services can be running or not, depending on the load of the machine that hosts them.

So the first time in the day, the userX access to the url userX.mydomain.com, the http server hosting the serviceX has to be started.

I already managed, thanks to haproxy, xinetd, some bash script, and the "HTTP Refresh header directive" to perform a refresh after the http server/service start..

but now I would like to make it even better, to let the "http service starting" to be transparent to the client asking for a GET, a PUT or a POST, and to immediately reply correctly, with the correct service response even at the first http request.

So I will need to start the service and then immediately proxying the request to the service just started.

I already try the "http-check" and "check" options in haproxy but I don't think they can be useful to me, because the healt checks are asynchrnous to the request handling of haproxy. Instead, I will need to perform this script execution for each request and before that haproxy proxies the request..

If squid allows to perform this kind of action, I can even let haproxy to proxy the request to squid, that then, can start the service and proxy the request

Does someone have an idea to achieve it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using proxymachine - https://github.com/mojombo/proxymachine

Basically proxymachine can intercept the HTTP request, parse the headers, run arbitrary Ruby code, and then forward the connection.

You would need to terminate the SSL prior to proxymachine getting the connection - e.g. using haproxy (with the new SSL capability).